# HTML5 validation & custom autofocus position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building web form where I'm using simple HTML5 validation.

```
<input type="text" required />
```

By default, when I click on the "SUBMIT" button browser HTML5 validation would kick in, scroll the page and focus on the empty required field. Problem is that browser would scroll up just enough to place the field inside viewport, at a very top of the screen. In some cases I might have absolute positioned elements at a top that would overlap the field.

I wonder if it's possible to scroll, let's say 100px more when validation kicks in, or even move the filed to the middle of the screen.

Note that I'm looking for simple JS or CSS solution that works with default HTML5 validation. I'm aware that I can achieve this if I implement custom validation script but I'm trying to stay lean.

Thanks

Comment: why not this `$("#id").focus()`

Comment: OPUS: That would do exactly the same

Answer (score 2):

You could trigger the validation youself with `checkValidity()`, and if that returns false, scroll another 100px down (because `checkValidity()` allready pushes you to the element).

If you set the form to 'novalidate' and than onsubmit check the form, you have a better control over it.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I'll give it a try now.